# Geo Fencing accuracy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, geolocation, geocoding

I have been wanting to automate jobs sent out to owners of areas within my business automatically and remove the need to find out who owns the closest area to the customer wanting work done.

My problem is a area owned by a tradesman is not set by postcodes, suburb names, city names etc. It is a customised area drawn out on a map.

I have not come accross a solution as of yet, however im hoping GEO Fencing can help me. Currently i can find only pre-made patterns like circles, polygons etc. They are not accurate enough due to the nature of the areas. Some areas are literally on the border of each other and again they are not circles or polygon shapes. They are literally drawn out randomly just like a country border would be.

I know i can use a drawing tool on google maps for example to re-draw them. However i dont think you can then store those drawn out areas in a long and lat as it just wouldnt work.

Does anyone have any solution for me?

Comment: the  problem is not draw the complex  polygon (this is possible and easy to do) also the accuracy is not a big problem  normally a GPS moble is few meter accurate .. but the problem is the algoritm for know if a position is inside the polygon  .. google maps have not this feature  ..but you can use a database gemtry extension for this  ..like  mysql

Comment: Ok well my current web software runs on PHP and MySQL. are there any tools that export the drawn out areas into something I can put in a database? From there I may be able to work the rest out.

Comment: then  another problem is related  tio the difference between the google coord and the mysql geometry coord..   but all of this is solved  with some studies .. for import polygon and conversione you can use a GIS like Quantum GIS (QGIS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after all. By creating a KML file i can draw out and re-create the areas i need. Once i have done that i can export the KML file.

You can then convert the KML file to Google maps API and generate google maps polygons based on that data.

You can then query a long and lat and see what polygon it falls into.

Once i finish it up I will try to remember to leave a snippet for an example.